# Microsoft Access VBA Error 461

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I cannot figure out why I keep getting error #461, *"Method or data member not found"*.

```
Private Sub cmdUpdate_Click()
    CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE Parts " _
        & "SET [In-Week 1] = " & Me.in1 & ", [In-Week 2] = " & Me.in2 & ", [In-Week 3] = " & Me.in3 _
        & ", [In-Week 4] = " & Me.in4 & ", [In-Week 5] = " & Me.in5 & ", [In-Week 6] = " & Me.in6 & ", [In-Week 7] = " & Me.in7 _
        & ", [In-Week 8] = " & Me.in8 & ", [In-Week 9] = " & Me.in9 & ", [In-Week 10] = " & Me.in10 & ", [In-Week 11] = " & Me.in11 _
        & ", [In-Week 12] = " & Me.in12 & ", [In-Week 13] = " & Me.in13 & ", [In-Week 14] = " & Me.in14 & ", [In-Week 15] = " & Me.in15 _
        & ", [In-Week 16] = " & Me.in16 & ", [In-Week 17] = " & Me.in17 & ", [In-Week 18] = " & Me.in18 & ", [In-Week 19] = " & Me.in19 _
        & ", [In-Week 20] = " & Me.in20 & ", [In-Week 21] = " & Me.in21 & ", [In-Week 22] = " & Me.in22 & ", [In-Week 23] = " & Me.in23 _
        & ", [In-Week 24] = " & Me.in24 & ", [In-Week 25] = " & Me.in25 & ", [In-Week 26] = " & Me.in26 & ", [In-Week 27] = " & Me.in27 _
        & ", [In-Week 28] = " & Me.in28 & ", [In-Week 29] = " & Me.in29 & ", [In-Week 30] = " & Me.in30 & ", [In-Week 31] = " & Me.in31 _
        & ", [In-Week 32] = " & Me.in32 & ", [In-Week 33] = " & Me.in33 & ", [In-Week 34] = " & Me.in34 & ", [In-Week 35] = " & Me.in35 _
        & ", [In-Week 36] = " & Me.in36 & ", [In-Week 37] = " & Me.in37 & ", [In-Week 38] = " & Me.in38 & ", [In-Week 39] = " & Me.in39 _
        & ", [In-Week 40] = " & Me.in40 & ", [In-Week 41] = " & Me.in41 & ", [In-Week 42] = " & Me.in42 & ", [In-Week 43] = " & Me.in43 _
        & ", [In-Week 44] = " & Me.in44 & ", [In-Week 45] = " & Me.in45 & ", [In-Week 46] = " & Me.in46 & ", [In-Week 47] = " & Me.in47 _
        & ", [In-Week 48] = " & Me.in48 & ", [In-Week 49] = " & Me.in49 & ", [In-Week 50] = " & Me.in50 & ", [In-Week 51] = " & Me.in51 & ", [In-Week 52] = " & Me.in52 & "  " _
        & "WHERE [Part #] = '" & txtFindPart & "';"
```

After I click my button it runs the error and highlights `Private Sub cmdUpdate_Click()` in yellow and `.in4` in the normal cursor highlight.

I have made sure all parts are typed correctly and that they exist in the form linked to the VBA script.

Comment: What is the full error message?

Comment: Error #461 is *"Method or data member not found"*.  From your description, it sounds like Access doesn't recognize `Me.in4`.  Insert a line just before `CurrentDb.Execute`, and add `MsgBox Me.in4` to that line.  Does Access now throw the error at that new line when you run the code?

Comment: @Newd- Compile Error: Method or data member not found

Comment: @HansUp - yes it still gave me the error message.

Comment: Then Access does not find an item named `in4` in the current form.  Either the name is wrong or the form is corrupted.  What is `in4` supposed to be?  A text box?  Something else?

Comment: InventoryAdjustments Form on [Inventory](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8N95pHWUYBjVVo5NU1kOHVPd2M/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Access does **not** throw an error on the `MsgBox Me.in4` line I asked you to include.

Comment: My apologies I read your comment wrong I thought you wanted to know if I still got the error.

Comment: Surprise it hasn't been mentioned yet, but you should really re-evaluate your table structure. That many fields on one form is generally an indicator of improperly designed tables. Looking at your table, this is most definitely true. Also while it may not be "wrong" it considered bad practice to use special characters and spaces in your column name. Also, you should use something simplier for your primary key, like an autonumber field instead of the part#.

Comment: Also you could skip the query completely if you used the table 'Parts' as the record source for your form, and had the part# field look up the record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems Access got confused with that code which builds the monstrous `UPDATE` string.  And it complained about `Me.in4` when the real problem is that `Me.in5` does not exist.  When you examine the text box you think is named *in5*, you will find its name is actually *Text10in5*.

I tracked down the problem by adding this code to the beginning of *cmdUpdate_Click()*.  The first version threw an error when *i* = 5, so I put that value in a `Case` statement to ignore it and see whether any of the remaining values threw a similar error.  None of the other values threw an error.

```vb
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 52
    Select Case i
    Case 5
        ' pass: Text10in5
    Case Else
        Debug.Print Me.Controls("in" & i).Name
    End Select
Next
```

Although that was a useful debugging technique, the actual reason I showed it to you is because I think you should use a similar strategy to update *Parts*.  Open a `DAO.Recordset` with your target *Parts* row.  Then loop through those 52 text boxes and store their values to the corresponding *Parts* fields ...

```vb
For i = 1 To 52
    rs.Fields("In-Week " & i).Value = Nz(Me.Controls("in" & i).Value, 0)
Next
```

That should work assuming you rename *Text10in5* to *in5*.